# Import data from sqoop to hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import –connect “jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db” \
    –username=retail_dba –password=cloudera –table export1 –hive-import \
    –hive-table export_3 –create-hive-table –fields-terminated-by “|” \
    –lines-terminated-by “\n” –null-string nvl –null-non-string -2 –outdir java_files
```

If I use the above command it gives an error that

> either use split by or -m 1 for sequential import

when I used `split-by` it ignored `null` values and imported other into hive

Can you explain the reason?

Thanks
Varun

Comment: what column you used for split by ?

Comment: The table name is export1 in sql and it does not have a primary key. I used department_id with split-by

Comment: Please let me know the column for which you have null values , is it department_id ?

Comment: Table export1 has two columns and there is one row with null values in both the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The NULL value issues you are getting are not related to split-by.

Sqoop will by default import NULL values as string null. Hive is however using string \N to denote NULL values and therefore predicates dealing with NULL (like IS NULL) will not work correctly. You should append parameters --null-string and --null-non-string in case of import job or --input-null-string and --input-null-non-string in case of an export job if you wish to properly preserve NULL values. Because sqoop is using those parameters in generated code, you need to properly escape value \N to \N:

```
$ sqoop import  ... --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N'
```

Comment: If i use the same command as in question and just add -m it works..do you the rationale behind it?